# Batch to make new line after every space in FOR loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, output

I have a for loop that prints the results to a text file.  What I want to do is to make a new line for every item (items are space separated).

The original colors.txt file looks like this:

```
red
blue    yellow
cyan
pink    orange
azure
```

Desired output of newcolors.txt:

```
red
blue    
yellow
cyan
pink    
orange
azure
```

My current code is here:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=    " %%a in (C:\colors.txt) DO call echo %%a >> C:\newcolors.txt
```

My current(and incorrect) output is below, it is skipping the colors that are space separated:

```
red 
blue 
cyan 
pink 
azure
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are going to have to provide some concrete examples of what your input looks like and what you need for output.

Comment: My apologies.  I updated it.

Comment: How many items can be on one line?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your examples this should work for you.

```
 @echo off
 FOR /F "delims=" %%G in (C:\colors.txt) DO (
    FOR %%H IN (%%G) DO ECHO %%H>>C:\newcolors.txt
 )
```

Comment: `@echo off
>"C:\newcolors.txt" (
  FOR /F "delims=" %%G in (C:\colors.txt) DO (
    FOR %%H IN (%%G) DO ECHO %%H
  )
)` so the file is opened and closed only once